# Could we have path variables mapping without spring mvc?

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, web, servlet-3.0

I was wondering if it's possible to map path variables within a regular java servlet 3.0 in a similar fashion we can do with Spring MVC and its annotation @PathVariable. I want to be able to retrieve params in url like this http://someurl.com/catalog/{param}/

However, I don't intend to use spring mvc in this case.

So, is that possible only with servlets ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet you could do..

```
String[] pathParams = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
```

or

```
String[] pathParams = request.getServletPath().split("/");
String param1 = pathParams[0];
String param2 = pathParams[1];
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use serious solution you can use "UrlRewrite": http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: Could I use JAX-RS annotations instead?

Comment: Yes you can. And looks like it solves your problem better than urlrewrite.